# Calling UDF on Dataframe with Serialization Issue

Tags: apache-spark

I was looking at some examples on blogs of UDFs that appear to work, but in fact when I run them they give the infamous task not serializable error.

I find it strange that this is published and no such mention made. Running Spark 2.4.

Code, pretty straight forward something must have changed in Spark?:

```
def lowerRemoveAllWhitespace(s: String): String = {
  s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "")
}
val lowerRemoveAllWhitespaceUDF = udf[String, String](lowerRemoveAllWhitespace)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
 ("r1 ", 1, 1, 3, -2),
 ("r 2", 6, 4, -2, -2),
 ("r 3", 4, 1, 1, 0),
 ("r4", 1, 2, 4, 5)
 )).toDF("ID", "a", "b", "c", "d")

df.select(lowerRemoveAllWhitespaceUDF(col("ID"))).show(false)
```

returns:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

From this blog that I find good: https://medium.com/@mrpowers/spark-user-defined-functions-udfs-6c849e39443b

Something must have changed???

I looked at the top voted item here with an Object and extends Serializable but no joy either. Puzzled.

**EDIT**

Things seems to have changed, this format needed:

```
val squared = udf((s: Long) => s * s)
```

The Object approach still interest me why it failed.

Comment: Can you mention the version of spark you are using? I did not find the `createDF` method in the api docs

Comment: 2.4 is the version, some things have changed and the docs are unclear. I want a multi-line function but that appears difficult.

Comment: Has to be an issue the manuals appear not to be consistent I think.

Comment: That's not really not what is supported, but how you structure your code (which is BTW missing from your question, so unless someone seen your previous question it doesn't make much sense. Care to [edit] and include [mcve]?), The idea of dumping all code into object body, is just not good.

Comment: Though if you want a quick hack just replace the function with `val lowerRemoveAllWhitespace = (s: String) => {
  s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "")
}`

Comment: Not really getting your comment. The DEF is there, surely. But you are telling me we cannot have multi-line udf... The example above is postulated as working. @user10465355

Comment: Then you get this old fella:  error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
  lowerRemoveAllWhitespace(col("ID"))).show(false)

Comment: @user10465355  Bottom line this appeared to have worked in the past this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the error (tried on spark 1.6, 2.3, and 2.4), but I do remember facing this kind of error (long time ago). I'll put in my best guess.

The problem happens due to difference between Method and Function in scala. [As described in detail here](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html).

Short version of that is when you write `def` it is equivalent to methods in java, i.e part of a a class and can be invoked using the instance of the class.

When you write `udf((s: Long) => s * s)` it creates an instance of trait `Function1`. For this to happen an anonymous class implementing `Function1` is generated whose apply method is is something like `def apply(s: Long):Long= {s * s}`, and the instance of this class is passed as parameter to `udf`.

However when you write `udf[String, String](lowerRemoveAllWhitespace)` the method `lowerRemoveAllWhitespace` needs to be converted to `Function1` instance and passed to `udf`. This is where the serialization fails, since the apply method on this instance will try to invoke `lowerRemoveAllWhitespace` on instance of another object (which could not be serialized and sent to the worker jvm process) causing the exception.

Comment: The post implies it worked with Scala in the past. I have no reason to doubt that, so things do change on implementation. Could that be the case? https://medium.com/@mrpowers/spark-user-defined-functions-udfs-6c849e39443b looks like Scala to me.

Comment: I not sure about the spark version they used. `createDF` method is not part of the spark 1.6, 2.3 or 2.4. But this issue has nothing to do with spark version. I do not remember exactly circumstances which caused the exception for me. However I remember you would not see this when running in local mode (all workers are witin same JVM) so no serialization happens. However when I was using spark-shell with yarn-client mode I used to see this.

Comment: And on DataBricks you see as well. I am pretty sure seruialization occurs in many cases on spark-shell in local as well. I am looking at it now - mapR.

Comment: I think you may take my point some areas are less clear here. Being a Big Data programmer is not for everyone.

Comment: My guess is that this happens only when you run an interactive shell (spark-shell, pyspark, zepplin notebook, jupyter-notebook) with yarn-client mode. since the code you type in has to be compiled and serilized and sent to worker nodes/processes

Comment: mapR just starts, I sometimes start with YARN expressly, but the greater point is a lot of stuff is misleading.

Comment: I would say that a lot of tutorials and examples are old or do not explain the corner cases, like serialization error. But when you get a hang of things you would start seeing these less often. Try to sick to official documentation as much as possible.

Comment: I think we can agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

The example that was posted was from a reputable source, but I cannot get to run without a Serialization error in Spark 2.4, trying of Objects etc. did not help either.

I solved the issue as follows using the udf(( .. approach which looks like a single statement only possible and indeed I could that and voila no serialization. A slightly different example though using primitives.

```
val sumContributionsPlus  = udf((n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int, n4: Int) => Seq(n1,n2,n3,n4).foldLeft(0)( (acc, a) => if (a > 0) acc + a else acc))
```

On a final note, the whole discussion on UDF, Spark native, columns UDFs is confusing when things no longer appear to work.