# Task not serializable when using a function with map in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Yet another "task not serializable" question. Sorry new to Scala and Spark so struggling a bit...

So I have an object with a method

```
object transformations {

  def someMethod()(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

      df.as[SomeCaseClass]
         .map(x => AnotherCaseClass(x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, x.col4.map(
          y => YetAnotherCaseClass(y.a.toString + '_' + y.b, y.c, y.d))
        )
        .toDF

  } 
}
```

and I would like to take the string manipulation outside so it can be reused. So if I do something like this:

```
object transformations {

  def manipulateString()(a: Int, b: String): String = {
    return a.toString + '_' + b
  } 

  def someMethod()(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

      df.as[SomeCaseClass]
         .map(x => AnotherCaseClass(x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, x.col4.map(
          y => YetAnotherCaseClass(transformations.manipulateString(y.a, y.b), y.c, y.d))
        )
        .toDF

  } 
}
```

I get the task not serializable error.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more info about the spark version you are using? How are you running the code (spark-shell, spark-submit) and the master (local, yarn-client, yarn-cluster)? If possible can you also provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also please look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086845/calling-udf-on-dataframe-with-serialization-issue) However it is difficult to understand why this happens without reproducing the error.

Comment: How will you use the transformations object? Why do you use someMethod()(df: DataFrame) instead of simply someMethod(df: DataFrame)?

Comment: I couldn't able to reproduce the issue. Can you please provide dependencies which you have used.

Comment: You're right @astro_asz

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for help everyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the transformations.manipulateString. It should be just manipulateString